# Why addEventListener not working on an appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a couple of "a" elements at the load of the webpage like this, with a default class called "link-block-2", and with a custom id. Then, I add an image inside this "a" element with an image:

```
function creatediv(div_projectname) {
  var div1 = document.createElement('a');
  div1.className = "link-block-2";
  div1.setAttribute("id", `${div_projectname}_btn`);
  document.getElementById('div-container-other-projects').appendChild(div1); 
  //add div for image
  var divimage = document.createElement('div');
  divimage.className = "div-block-7";
  document.getElementById(`${div_projectname}_btn`).appendChild(divimage)
}
```

And this is the finall result:

```
    <div class="div-block" id="div-container-other-projects">
      <a class="link-block-2" id="p1_btn"><div class="div-block-7" id="p1_btn"></div></a>
      <a class="link-block-2" id="p2_btn"><div class="div-block-7" id="p2_btn"></div></a>
      <a class="link-block-2" id="p3_btn"><div class="div-block-7" id="p3_btn"></div></a>
      <a class="link-block-2" id="p4_btn"><div class="div-block-7" id="p4_btn"></div></a>
    </div>
```

I have a function where I detect which "a" element I click:

```
const buttonscontainer = document.getElementById('div-container-other-projects')
buttonscontainer.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const target = event.target
  if (target.className !== 'link-block-2') return
  Array.from(buttonscontainer.children).forEach(child =>
    child.classList.remove('link-block-2--selected'))
  target.classList.add('link-block-2--selected')
})
```

This doesn't work because of, when I click on the div appended that has an image (id="p1_btn","p2_btn"..) does not recognize that I am clickin because of the z-index value. I think that by default the div with an image that I append after the "a" element has a zindex value superior than the "a", but no matter what I put on the css class (zindex=100, position aboslute, relative..) that the last div that I append has a zindex bigger thant the previous "a" and the click event listener doesnt work...

I've tried a lot of other solutions and doesn't really work as I want, anyone can help?

Thanks!:)

Comment: One way to solve this issue is to add the click event listener to the inner div element instead of the outer a element. This way, when you click on the div, the event will propagate up to the parent a element and trigger the event listener.

Comment: I've thought that, the problem is that the div that I append on the "a" element does not cover the whole "a", it is like width=50% and height=50%, so does not cover the whole click region of the "a".. Thanks!

Comment: is the function that creates the const out of all elements run before or after all elements have been created?

Comment: it runs after the creatediv function, why?

Comment: Common rookie mistake to add an eventListener to elements before they are created dynamically and as such they don't have an eventListener. PS: Event Delegation and `classList.toggle` would cut down your code by more then 50%

Comment: Hi @tacoshy , thanks for your response, I create all the divs, and then I declare the const add event listener function on another script.js that I execute at the end of the creatediv(). I'm declaring it wrong? Also thanks for the "toggle" thing, but I need to work with this class method for other reasons.